# Get rid of high order derivatives in multi-derivative symbolic expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have the following expression:

```
FullSimplify[D[D[E^(1/2 J [t1, t2]*G*J[t1, t2]), {t1, 3}], {t2, 3} ]]
```

It's output is pretty nasty. It has some combinations of derivatives of $J(t1,t2)$ that look like $J^{(i,j)}$. I wish to keep only terms such that $i+j=2$, that is terms which have exactly two derivatives of $J$ (no matter by which parameters, but I need to keep track how much of each I have).

My *Mathematica* skills are very basic so simple (not necessary efficient) solution is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

There are still many terms, but a simple replacement rule will work. The following sets all instances of a derivative of `J` of order greater than 2 to zero:

```
expr = D[D[E^(1/2 J[t1, t2]*G*J[t1, t2]), {t1, 3}], {t2, 3}];
expr /. Derivative[ns__][_][__] /; Total@{ns} >= 2 :> 0
```

[image]